# I am trying to loop through my counter to create a dynamic sql query which should finally look like

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to loop through my counter to create a dynamic sql query which should finally look like

I am trying to use this approach to get the final query but does not seems to work

```
declare @CurrentRow int
set @CurrentRow =0;
declare @RowsToProcess int
declare @FinalHistoricalQuery varchar(5000)
WHILE @CurrentRow<3
BEGIN      
   SET @FinalHistoricalQuery =' select 11'+convert(varchar(20),@CurrentRow) + ' union '
   SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
END

SET @FinalHistoricalQuery = left(@FinalHistoricalQuery,len(@FinalHistoricalQuery)-6)
exec (@FinalHistoricalQuery)
```

The final output that i am looking for is `110 111 112` but it comes as `112` Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server? What should the generated query look like (looks like you forgot to include that)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `@FinalHistoricalQuery` before the loop and you need to use it in on the left side if the assignment in the loop.

```
declare @CurrentRow int
set @CurrentRow =0;
declare @RowsToProcess int
declare @FinalHistoricalQuery varchar(5000)

-- Set a start value
set @FinalHistoricalQuery = ''

WHILE @CurrentRow<3
BEGIN      
                              -- Use variable here
   SET @FinalHistoricalQuery = @FinalHistoricalQuery + ' select 11'+convert(varchar(20),@CurrentRow) + ' union '
   SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
END

SET @FinalHistoricalQuery = left(@FinalHistoricalQuery,len(@FinalHistoricalQuery)-6)

exec (@FinalHistoricalQuery)
```

Result:

```
-----------
110
111
112

(3 row(s) affected)
```